# "grep: line too long" error message

Tags: grep

I used the following syntax in order to find IP address under `/etc`

(answered by Dennis Williamson in superuser site)

but I get the message "grep: line too long".

Someone have idea how to ignore this message and why I get this?

```
  grep -Er '\<([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\>' /etc/
  grep: line too long
```

Answer (score 24):

The find/xargs solution didn't work for me, but resulted in the same error.

I solved this problem by using the `-I` grep option (ignore binary files). In my case there must have been a binary file in the list of files to search that had no linebreaks, so grep tries to read in a gigantic line that is too big. That's my guess at what this error means.

I got the idea from: http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/am8x7wI0r0243prrmYd4

This might not work for you of course if there's a text file with a line that is too long.

Comment: Just to make clear for others, the option is capital I ("-I") as in India, not an "l" as in lima.

Comment: @riderchap Glad I read your comment. I'll give it a try with the cap-I later. From the answers on this one from Shorin and the answer by jmtd, it seems there's two issues. One issue where the list of files is too long, then an issue were the actual line in a file is too long. In my case it was the list of files and jmtd option is best. For the case where the line in a file is too long, it seems Shorin's option would be best, but I don't have a case to try it. It might also be possible that ignoring the binaries dropped Shorin below the threshold for the maximum count in the list of files.

Comment: Ah! Thanks. I made it look like an India instead of Lima.

Answer (score 4):

Use find to build a list of files to grep,

```
find /etc -type f -print0 | xargs -r0 grep -E '\<([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\>'
```

In general find is a more flexible way of traversing the filesystem and building lists of files for other programs.

Comment: The error message does not come from the shell, i.e. it is not a problem of an argument list, which got too long.

Comment: Yes, and find/xargs are often used to solve *that* problem. This isn't that problem, but using find/xargs solves it nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your grep has a bug and scans by accident a binary file with too long lines (i.e. too much characters for grep to handle between two newlines). See [this red hat page for more details](https://web.archive.org/web/20090906133605/http://www.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5.4/html/Technical_Notes/grep.html) ([bug page](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=483073)).