# How to grep a huge XML file?

Tags: xml, linux, file, grep

I am trying to grep in an xml file which is 13GB and I am getting this error below. Actually I need to grep for this pattern and identify the line and transfer the data in the xml file to an excel file.

```
home/jale% zgrep -i "Forward Challenge Curly WUT" *filename*
```

> grep: line too long
>
> grep: line too long

Comment: Are you grepping single or multiple files? Is XML file(s) is/are compressed that you use `grep`?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["grep: line too long" error message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3657236/grep-line-too-long-error-message)

Comment: I wonder if an XML parser would be more effective in this case (like `xmllint --xpath ...`)?  Because where `grep` is line-oriented, an XML parser is not and may deal better with the input.

Comment: Also related: [line too long error when trying to search log files](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12680973/55075)

Comment: @kenorb Looks like the solution to that question was to ignore binary files (OP here presupposes that he's not working with binary files).

Comment: In my understanding using `zgrep` it-self indicates the work with binary files (archives). What if the file isn't zipped? Using wildcards suggests working with multiple files, however the title saying otherwise. Maybe `*filename*.gz` should work better or whatever the files are being grepped? In my opinion the question is not clear enough, it's a bit ambiguous.

Comment: It is a .Z file. I also tried to grep the pattern by uncompromising the file , still i got the same error.Even if I try to get a single from the file by head -2 command , i am getting a huge output which is not readable. Please let me know. Thanks

Comment: @Lara Is *filename* reaching only one file? Can you just try specifying exact filename, instead of using wildcard to rule out some multiple or binary files? Does it work with single file? Does it work, when you're working on single uncompressed .xml file?

Comment: Why not to use specific xmlgrep for that?

Answer (score 0):

Use an XML parser like [XPATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) instead of GREP. GREP is not designed for searching in XML files, and the parsers are.

> XPath, the XML Path Language, is a query language for selecting nodes
>   from an XML document. In addition, XPath may be used to compute values
>   (e.g., strings, numbers, or Boolean values) from the content of an XML
>   document. XPath was defined by the World Wide Web Consortium (W3C).

Comment: Unfortunately, though, most XPath processors rely on holding the whole XML file in memory.

Comment: There will be some of them which will read it by parts, made for big size files. You can investigate.